# iOS: how to remove xib files caching?

Tags: iphone, ios, caching, xib

My application is localized in two languages. I have pairs of xib files for the two localizations. When I change the device/simulator language, or when I modify xib files and rebuild-run the application, the old xib files are still used in the application, seem to be cached somewhere. How to tell my app to delete cached xib files?

**Edit:**
Check this scene:
On device, I run the app while the device language is English, all xib files are English. Then I change device language to Arabic, restart the device, Xib files still english!

what is the problem? and how to solve it?

Comment: Please Reset or delete the build  in simulator and again run project

Answer (score 3):

From Xcode:

- Build Menu -> Clean

and/or

- Delete app from simulator

(usually I do both)

Make sure the xib are only in the localized directories